# how to specify external software requirements with conda/meta.yaml in Python?

Tags: python, travis-ci, anaconda, conda

I am writing a `meta.yaml` file for a python package to be used in conda packages in a way that works with CI systems. how can i specify external software requirements for the package? meaning software that is not a python library but is required for the package unit tests to pass? **to clarify**: the required module is not a python package, but the python package depends on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements in the meta.yaml can be any conda package (which doesn't have to just be Python packages). If you have a conda package for your dependency, you can specify it.

Comment: what if you don't have a conda package for it? is there a way to add a "pre-build" step that downloads the .tar.gz and builds it with standard steps (``./configure; make``,...)?

Comment: You should make and build a recipe for them. See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build.html and http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials.html.

Comment: what if the package is on binstar.org on some user's channel and i want to declare that as dependency in ``meta.yaml``? simply putting the package name does not work since conda cant find it

Comment: You'll have to add the channel to your configuration, with `conda config --add channels channelname`.

Comment: thanks but just noticed that on binstar.org some packages registered as only for linux (even when they should be osx compatible), eg https://binstar.org/minadyn/gitpython . i can't then have them as prerequisites because my package (which works on osx and linux) will not work on osx because of this dependency. i thought all conda packages are cross platform?

Comment: conda itself is cross platform, but most packages are only built for a specific platform.  If a package is pure Python, you can use `conda convert` to convert it to another platform (or use `conda skeleton pypi` to create a recipe and build it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build.html), there's a `requirements` section where you can specify build and run dependencies.

Comment: those are just python packages it seems like

Comment: They are not just python packages, you should use this section for system libraries as well. However, I don't think its possible to specify a channel.